# mysqli_real_eascape_string gives error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a problem with mysql real escape string.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
else{ echo"connected";}
?>
```

Now it echos connection. so this works fine. (I tried adding stuff into the db and that also works fine.

Now I try to do a mysqli_real_escape_string like this:

```
$email_address = $con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

But this gives me a error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysql_escape_string() in
>   Blabla/blabla.php on line 15

(the line where I call the escape string)

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your message says `mysqli::mysql_escape_string()`. Your code is wrong at this point since it should be `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. The line you posted is correct, so look elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you don't have your sql in your question here 2 examples:

Object oriented style

```
$city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($city);
```

or the procedural style

```
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);
```

For more information see this: [php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Also see Prepare statements this is better than `mysqli_real_escape_string` [php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 2):

Change to:

```
$email_address = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Check the manual:
http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string